# SQL Split a column onto a different row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

Hopefully I can explain this properly.  I have this code which extracts the data onto excel.  What I want to happen is to show detail for acquisition etc on one line and then show the same info again but showing the disposal amount as currently both values being shown on the same line isn't good for the user.

the code I have to get the data is this

```
DECLARE @DateNull DATE;
SET @DateNull = CAST('1900/01/01' AS DATE)

set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
select 
a.DataAreaId,
a.AssetId AS AssetNumber,
a.Name as AssetName,
a.AssetGroup,
CASE WHEN b.Status = 0 then 'Not yet aquired' 
 WHEN b.Status = 1 then 'Open' 
 WHEN b.Status = 2 then 'Suspeneded' 
 WHEN b.Status = 3 then 'Closed' 
 WHEN b.Status = 4 then 'Sold' 
 WHEN b.Status = 5 then 'Scrapped' 
 WHEN b.Status = 6 then 'Transfered to low value pool'  END as 

AssetStatus,
NULLIF(b.AcquisitionDate,@DateNull) AS AcquisitionDate,
(b.ServiceLife) AS ServiceLife,
NULLIF(b.DisposalDate,@DateNull) AS DisposalDate,
AquisitionPrice.AmountMST*-1 As Aquisition,
--ISNULL(AquisitionPrice.AquisitionMonth,@DateNull) AS AquisitionMonth,
Depreciation.AmountMST*-1 As Depreciation,
NULLIF(Depreciation.DepreciationMonth,@DateNull) AS DepreciationMonth,
Disposal.AmountMST*-1 AS DisposalAmount,
--ISNULL(Disposal.DisposalMonth,@DateNull) AS DisposalMonth,
dv.OperatingDivision



    from assettable a
    Inner join AssetBook b
        ON a.assetid=b.assetid
        and a.dataareaid=b.dataareaid
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.PSV_AX_KPIDefaultDimensionView  DV
            ON b.DefaultDimension =  dv.DefaultDimension
    LEFT JOIN 
        (select        AssetID,BookId,DataAreaId,/*LowValuePoolType_AU,Reclassification*/
            --DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TRANSDATE), 0) AS AquisitionMonth,
            TransType,SUM(AmountMST) AS AmountMST,SUm(RevaluationAmount) AS RevaluationAmount from AssetTrans
            WHERE TransType =1 /*Aquisition*/Or TRANSTYPE =2 /*AcquisitionAdj*/
            GROUP BY AssetID,BookId,DataAreaId,TransType

        --DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TRANSDATE), 0)
    ) AquisitionPrice
ON a.AssetId=AquisitionPrice.AssetId    
AND a.DataAreaId=AquisitionPrice.DataAreaId
AND b.BookId=AquisitionPrice.BookId
LEFT JOIN 
    (select AssetID,BookId,DataAreaId,/*LowValuePoolType_AU,Reclassification*/
        DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TRANSDATE), 0) AS DepreciationMonth,
        TransType,SUM(AmountMST) AS AmountMST,SUm(RevaluationAmount) AS RevaluationAmount from AssetTrans
        WHERE TransType =3 /*Depreciation*/Or TRANSTYPE =4 /*DepreciationAdj*/ 
        GROUP BY AssetID,BookId,DataAreaId,
                DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TRANSDATE), 0),
                TransType
    ) Depreciation
ON a.AssetId=Depreciation.AssetId   
AND a.DataAreaId=Depreciation.DataAreaId
AND b.BookId=Depreciation.BookId

Left join

    (select AssetID,BookId,DataAreaId,TransType,
        --DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TRANSDATE), 0) AS DisposalMonth,
        SUM(AmountMST) AS AmountMST,SUm(RevaluationAmount) AS RevaluationAmount from AssetTrans 
        WHERE TransType in (8,9) /*Disposal Sale,Disposal Scrap*/
        GROUP BY AssetID,BookId,DataAreaId,TransType
        --DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TRANSDATE), 0)
    ) Disposal  
ON a.AssetId=Disposal.AssetId   
AND a.DataAreaId=Disposal.DataAreaId
AND b.BookId=Disposal.BookId
```

Comment: "isn't good for the user" is not a clear problem description. add which implementation (read: server version) of SQL you're using, define clearly what you need, and what you get instead.

Comment: Tag the dbms product used. (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.) Add sample table data, and the expected result. And it would be great if you could minimize the problem - too much text as it is now!

Comment: Do you mean return 2 rows instead of every currently returned row? And those 2 rows must be the same but first with `null AS DisposalAmount` and the second with `Disposal.AmountMST*-1 AS DisposalAmount`?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this.  Here is sample result

Comment: What is the desired result ?

Comment: for example I would like to show first line of info with the aqusition value and then show the first line again but with the disposal value and it would continue like that so there is 2 lines for each asset.  So I think what you've said above is correct.  I did attached a picture but not sure it's worked

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this whole scenario generally a bad idea, you can achieve this by `UNION`ing your Acquisition and Depreciation data together in your join, which will give you the two rows.  Then you need to use a `CASE` statement to check which one to show.

You will need to handle the `null` values I have put into the `ELSE` part of the `CASE` in your excel sheet if you are not using Data Connected Tables.

I would also recommend cleaning up your code.  Your formatting is rather inconsistent to say the least and you have a couple different spellings for 'Acquisition' in the same script...

Not having the data to try this on I do not know if it will work as is, but it should get you on your way:

```
DECLARE @DateNull DATE;
SET @DateNull = CAST('1900/01/01' AS DATE)

set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
select 
a.DataAreaId,
a.AssetId AS AssetNumber,
a.Name as AssetName,
a.AssetGroup,
CASE WHEN b.Status = 0 then 'Not yet aquired' 
 WHEN b.Status = 1 then 'Open' 
 WHEN b.Status = 2 then 'Suspeneded' 
 WHEN b.Status = 3 then 'Closed' 
 WHEN b.Status = 4 then 'Sold' 
 WHEN b.Status = 5 then 'Scrapped' 
 WHEN b.Status = 6 then 'Transfered to low value pool'  END as 

AssetStatus,
case when APD.APDType = 'AcquisitionPrice' then NULLIF(b.AcquisitionDate,@DateNull) else null end AS AcquisitionDate,
case when APD.APDType = 'AcquisitionPrice' then (b.ServiceLife) else null end AS ServiceLife,
case when APD.APDType = 'AcquisitionPrice' then NULLIF(b.DisposalDate,@DateNull) else null end AS DisposalDate,
case when APD.APDType = 'AcquisitionPrice' then APD.AmountMST*-1 else null end As Aquisition,
--ISNULL(AquisitionPrice.AquisitionMonth,@DateNull) AS AquisitionMonth,

case when APD.APDType = 'Depreciation' then APD.AmountMST*-1 else null end As Depreciation,
case when APD.APDType = 'Depreciation' then NULLIF(APD.DepreciationMonth,@DateNull) else null end AS DepreciationMonth,
case when APD.APDType = 'Depreciation' then APD.AmountMST*-1 AS else null end DisposalAmount,
--ISNULL(Disposal.DisposalMonth,@DateNull) AS DisposalMonth,

dv.OperatingDivision



    from assettable a
    Inner join AssetBook b
        ON a.assetid=b.assetid
        and a.dataareaid=b.dataareaid
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.PSV_AX_KPIDefaultDimensionView  DV
            ON b.DefaultDimension =  dv.DefaultDimension
    LEFT JOIN 
        (select 'AcquisitionPrice' as APDType, AssetID,BookId,DataAreaId,/*LowValuePoolType_AU,Reclassification*/
            --DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TRANSDATE), 0) AS AquisitionMonth,
            TransType,SUM(AmountMST) AS AmountMST,SUm(RevaluationAmount) AS RevaluationAmount from AssetTrans
            WHERE TransType =1 /*Aquisition*/Or TRANSTYPE =2 /*AcquisitionAdj*/
            GROUP BY AssetID,BookId,DataAreaId,TransType

        --DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TRANSDATE), 0)

        union all 

        select 'Depreciation' as APDType,  AssetID,BookId,DataAreaId,/*LowValuePoolType_AU,Reclassification*/
        DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TRANSDATE), 0) AS DepreciationMonth,
        TransType,SUM(AmountMST) AS AmountMST,SUm(RevaluationAmount) AS RevaluationAmount from AssetTrans
        WHERE TransType =3 /*Depreciation*/Or TRANSTYPE =4 /*DepreciationAdj*/ 
        GROUP BY AssetID,BookId,DataAreaId,
                DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TRANSDATE), 0),
                TransType
    ) APDepreciation
ON a.AssetId=APD.AssetId    
AND a.DataAreaId=APD.DataAreaId
AND b.BookId=APD.BookId


Left join

    (select AssetID,BookId,DataAreaId,TransType,
        --DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TRANSDATE), 0) AS DisposalMonth,
        SUM(AmountMST) AS AmountMST,SUm(RevaluationAmount) AS RevaluationAmount from AssetTrans 
        WHERE TransType in (8,9) /*Disposal Sale,Disposal Scrap*/
        GROUP BY AssetID,BookId,DataAreaId,TransType
        --DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TRANSDATE), 0)
    ) Disposal  
ON a.AssetId=Disposal.AssetId   
AND a.DataAreaId=Disposal.DataAreaId
AND b.BookId=Disposal.BookId
```